# How can I update geojson properties using popup leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, web-mapping

I have GeoJSON file named json_point2. This file holds point data as follows:

```
var json_point2={
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Class": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 40.193168611061743, 40.904508523555492 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Class": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 40.191358449981372, 40.902051540140285 ] } },
```

When I click this point on my web apps, I want to enter input value on popup and save this value geojson Class properties.

I can click on the point with the following code and enter the attribute. But he does not record it in his database.

My code:

```
map.createPane('pane_point2');
map.getPane('pane_point2').style.zIndex = 602;
map.getPane('pane_point2').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
var layer_point2 = new L.geoJson(json_point2, {
    attribution: '<a href=""></a>',
    pane: 'pane_point2',
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var input = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'my-input');
        input.value = feature.properties.Class;
        L.DomEvent.addListener(input, 'change', function () {
            feature.properties.Class = input.value;
        });
        layer.bindPopup(input);

    }   
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I suppose `L.DomUtil.create` doesn't change the .geojson file. For that purpose I would recommend you to use http://geojson.io/ service. After adding some features there you may easily rewrite your .geojson. It works great with the GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

The `new L.geoJson(json_point2...` just loads the geojson content and create an instance of L.geoJson object. It is normal the modifications of the L.geoJon does not affect the initial JSON variable.

Somewhere in your code, you have to call :

```
var new_json_point2 = layer_point2.toGeoJSON();
```

to get a JSON representation of the `layer_point2` layer.